# ApplyLinearImpulse doesnt work when called within UIPanGestureRecognizer function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am using Box2d and Cocos2d to develop an iPhone game.  I have a ball in the center of the screen with a simple boundary created using fixtures etc. What I want to do is add the functionality so that a user can "swipe" the ball to apply force and basically flick it across the screen.

I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(30, 30);
_body->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, _ballBodyDef->position);
```

If I apply a linear impulse during the init function the ball fires off in the correct direction and behaves as it should do. It doesnt do anything, however, if I put it into the `handlePan` function that is called when a gesture is done by the user.  Here is the full code for the function: (Note that the `NSLog` writes out the correct information.

```
- (void)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:recognizer.view];

            NSLog(@"Vel: %f, newPos: %f",velocity.x,velocity.y);

            b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(30, 30);
            _body->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, _ballBodyDef->position);
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force you are applying in handlePanFrom is always b2Vec2(30, 30).  It will never change with your current code, and is therefore not going to move in your direction.

Comment: Hey Aaron, sorry but I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: You are applying a linear impulse to your body.  The force of this impulse is always set as b2Vec2(30, 30) in your code and will not change if left the way it is.  This means that your body will always move in the same direction, not in the direction of the swipe.  Your NSLog is outputting the correct coordinates because it is printing velocity.x and velocity.y, but your impulse is never actually using those values.

Comment: Yes I know, but whilst testing I wanted a constant force applied.  The problem is the body isnt moving at all in any direction!

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have misunderstood.  You are getting the position from the bodyDef.  I'm not sure if that is correct or not.  Try body->GetPosition();

Comment: I dont understand what you guys are saying.  Im using this code and it fails, inside my update method: self.body->ApplyLinearImpulse( b2Vec2(1,5000), self.body->GetWorldCenter() );
why should it not move the body?